# Boas práticas para evitar exibição de página quebrada?

Tags: ux

**Problema:**
Desenvolvi um site que ao ser carregado é exibido com alguns bugs, como imagens exibidas no lugar de uma outra que não foi carregada a tempo, formulários totalmente bugados e sem estilização nenhuma.

**Alternativa:**
Pressionar "F5", porém um usuário leigo, não vai imaginar que a página será recarregada corretamente após esta função, resultando na perda de confiança ou até mesmo a evasão do próprio.

**Pergunta:**
O que poderia ser feito afim de evitar que a página fosse exibida com quebras de marcação, ou estilização incompleta?

**OBS:**
O HTML está bem aplicado de forma semântica e a chamada do arquivo CSS externo está logo após o `title`.
Acredito que criando um loading em php ou js na tela pra que dispare a página somente após ser totalmente carregada já soluciona meu problema, mas estou disposto e aberto à novas soluções.

Comment: Cara, cria um simples loader em JS e você resolve o problema.
Se suas imagens possuem um tamanho padrão, ou agrupamentos padrão, defina classes css com altura e largura definidos e depois só aplica a classe na imagem... poupa código. Ex:
`<img class="img-media" ... >`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu layout é feito por imagens?

Se sim, uma das maneiras de contornar esse redimensionamento enquanto as imagens vão sendo carregadas é predefinir o tamanho das imagens.

Isso permite que o browser já reserve o espaço exato para a imagem. Além disso, se alguma imagem por ventura não vier a carregar, não irá atrapalhar o resto do layout (pelo menos o espaço que ela deveria ocupar o browser se encarregará de preencher, nem que seja com um *X* de erro).

Ao invés de apenas:

```html
<img src='http://meusite.dominio/imagem.extensao'>
```

Especificar também *width* e *height*:

```html
<img src='http://meusite.dominio/imagem.extensao" width='50' height='300'>
```

Uma desvantagem é ter que ficar marcando as tags *img* com estes atributos; mas ora pode ser necessário.

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro passo é identificar o problema. Existe um motivo pelo qual as imagens ou o `CSS` não carrega de forma correta. O posicionamento do `CSS` não esta diretamente ligado ao problema. O que pode estar acontecendo é o servidor encontrar problemas durante a transmissão dos arquivos.

Existe também a possibilidade de atualizar a página de forma automatica utilizando `JavaScript` quando a mesma terminar de carregar, porém isso não garante que as imagens carreguem. Neste caso seria necessario também o uso de `cookies` para saber quando é  a segunda vez que a página esta sendo carregada.

Já em relação ao script em `PHP`, isso não ira resolver seu problema. O que é possivel ser feito é a utilização de `lazy loading` ou `late loading`, que basicamente você carrega o recurso após a página ter sido carregada por completo. Com isso é possivel identificar quando um recurso não foi carregado de forma correta e tentar carregar o mesmo novamente. O problema é que isso gera problemas de performance quando o site possuir muitos recursos. Neste caso é possivel implementar um script `PHP` para auxiliar no processo, porém é totalmente possivel ser feito em `JavaScript`.

Uma solução mais estética seria definir todos os elementos com altura e largura fixas no `CSS`, dessa forma quando um elemento não carregar não ira causar grandes problemas de formação. Isso não se aplica caso o `CSS` não carregar.

Answer (score 1):

Exibir o html após carregar  - Js

```
body.onload=function(){document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.display='none';};
window.onload=function(){document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.display='block';};
```

Loader em PHP não vai te atender, porque PHP é server-side.. ou seja, ele vai renderizar sua página e após isto, que o navegador vai fazer o download do site, ou seja, depois do php trabalhar é que você vai baixar imagens, que é aonde o erro ocorre...

Definir tamanho de cada imagem também é uma boa, preserva o espaço alocado antes de baixar...

Definir tamanhos padrão de imagem ajuda.
Uma lida em responsividade, também ajuda.